# How to delete a row from gridview without loading page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one Gridview in my web page. That is having 2 link fields edit and delete. If i click that link that will load full page. That time data i am losing the data which was there in the grid view. The Data which was there in the grid view is coming from user one by one.

When I am trying to edit the data by clicking edit link that will load the page and tries to fetch the data from grid view. Here i observed that row count of Grid is 0. So i am unable to edit the data which is there in the grid.

Can any one tell me how i can do this?

Comment: you need to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i am not getting how to use this.

Comment: @Raghuveera: You can use Ajax Update panel , put ur gridview inside update panel refer [Tuts Gridview with Ajax UpdatePanel](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem correctly, you could try to save all the existing data rows BEFORE you are changing them.
There might be an "prechange" event which you could use to save the data befor they get lost.

1. save the data into a internal list
2. edit the selected data
3. refresh only the grid control with the new edited data.

Toby

Comment: when i click on edit link data which is there in that row need to come to the Textbox and that row i want to delete from the grid view.